# Apollo Client erroneously reads from cache when it should make network request

Tags: apollo, apollo-client, apollo-cache-inmemory

I have a series of Apollo queries that work as follows:

- Queries can be made to retrieve sub-resources from a specific `Website`
- Rather than pass the `Website` ID as an input arg, the Apollo server retrieves the ID from an HTTP header or cookie.
- The queries thus look something like this:

```
query {
  currentWebsite {
    id
    ...sub-resources
  }
}
```

This works well until the current website changes. This is because Apollo client already has a website in the cache, and will retrieve the first (and incorrect) website from the cache rather than make another HTTP request. I believe this is because the query does not contain a unique ID, so it treats all `currentWebsite` queries as the same.

Now I'm aware there are many ways this can be solved. Here are the ways I know, and the perceived drawbacks:

1. Update Apollo server to allow receiving `websiteId` as an input arg. I tested this and it works. Unfortunately, updating the API would be a lot of work.
2. Change the `fetchPolicy` from the default to something like `cache-and-network`. This is a quick fix, but will make more HTTP requests than it needs to.
3. Manually invalidate part of the cache when the website changes. This is my least favourite solution.
4. Manually read from the cache. If the query does not exist, call `useQuery` with a fieldPolicy like `network-only`. This feels very heavy handed.

Ultimately, I don't think any of these solutions are quite what I need. I feel there must be a way to provide the Apollo cache the website ID for each query such that it can determine by itself whether it should retrieve the website from the cache or get a new one. I find the Apollo cache rather opaque though and not sure where to start!

Answer (score 2):

So the trick here is to write a [custom `keyArgs` function](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-field-behavior/#fieldpolicy-api-reference) and utilize the fact that you can have client-side variables that aren't passed along to the server:

```
query GetWebsiteById($websiteId: String) {
  currentWebsite {
    id
    ...sub-resources
  }
}
```

Pass along whatever header value you have into `$websiteId` when you execute the query. Then you can read that variable in your `keyArgs` function.

```
const createCache = () => new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    Query: {
      fields: {
        currentWebsite: {
          keyArgs: (_, { variables }) => {
            if (variables?.websiteId == null) {
              return 'currentWebsite';
            } else {
              return `currentWebsite:${variables.websiteId}`;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Now it will store each query in the cache with its own unique id: `currentWebsite:1`, `currentWebsite:2`, etc.

Comment: Exactly what I needed!

Comment: Hm, I may have gotten ahead of myself. When doing this GraphqQL validation fails because `$websiteId` is not used: `GraphQLError: Variable \"$websiteId\" is never used in operation `

Comment: Hmmm that appears to be a known issue with Apollo server... https://github.com/apollographql/eslint-plugin-graphql/issues/19